# Automatically move iOS app icons to fill empty slots on previous page?

Tags: ios, ipad, applications, icon

On my non-jailbroken iPad running iOS 7.1.2 I'm deleting a number of apps that I've downloaded to try but don't want to keep. As I delete them app icons on the page move up to fill the empty spots. Is there some way to also have app icons from the next automatically move up to fill empty spots at the end of the current page?

Moving them individually is tedious. I could group them, move the group to the previous page, the nun group them but this too is a hassle. I'd prefer not to have to resort to iTunes to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not possible within iOS. You can provide feedback to Apple here:

- https://www.apple.com/feedback/iphone.html